# String without white space

Tags: java, android

So basically I am creating a quiz for my Android app. However I have noticed that when the user types in the correct answer which is "angry" and has a space next to it the answer appears as wrong. I am wondering how I could change this so that white space after the answer does not get included? Thanks!

```
public void question3(View view) {

        // Get the typed answer by the user and convert it to lower case.
        EditText question3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question3_typed); 

        String question3_answer = question3.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

        if (question3_answer.equals("angry")) {
            answer3 = "correct";
        } else answer3 = "wrong";
```

Comment: See [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()): `if (question3_answer.trim().equals("angry"))` ...

Comment: .trim() should do the trick.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use trim method of String class which removes any white space in the beginning or end of the string. Modify your code like this

```
public void question3(View view) {

    // Get the typed answer by the user and convert it to lower case.
    EditText question3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question3_typed); 

    String question3_answer = question3.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();

    if (question3_answer.equals("angry")) {
        answer3 = "correct";
    } else answer3 = "wrong";
```

Comment: it should be like this **`question3.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();`**

Comment: you might want to put that .trim() after the .toString()

Comment: Thanks. Updated the answer. Upvote it if i have helped you